# Add more field into header using interceptor of spring boot not work

Tags: spring-boot, interceptor

I'm using spring boot.
I want to add a field into header of every response. So that, i using interceptor. The code is:

```
@Component
public class ApiVersionInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter{
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApiVersionInterceptor.class);

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                Object handler, Exception arg3) throws Exception {
        String apiVersion = environment.getProperty(ApiVersion.VERSION_KEY.getKey());
        log.debug("api-version:"+apiVersion);
        response.addHeader("Api-Version", apiVersion);
    }
}
```

And the configuration is:

```
@Configuration
public class InterceptorsConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ApiVersionInterceptor apiVersionInterceptor;

    /**
     * Add interceptor
     */
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(final InterceptorRegistry registry) {

        //Add api-version field to header of response
        registry.addInterceptor(apiVersionInterceptor);
    }

}
```

To make sure this snipped code is run because of:

```
2017-12-06 02:35:10,392 DEBUG [] [http-nio-8080-exec-7] ApiVersionInterceptor: api-version:1.9.0
```

But i don't understand, i don't see this field in the header of any response.

**Update**

My app use Restful webservice, so don't have view phase.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You should add header in a earlier phase, override the `preHandle` method in your `ApiVersionInterceptor`. Because in `afterCompletion` response is already committed and skip header changes.

Comment: If i use `prehandle()` or `postHandle()`. Nothing happen.

Comment: I created small demo as you, and checked by restClient there is a link [ScreenShot](http://prntscr.com/hjq9lj) to the screenshot. It is strange, why it did not work for you. If need i can push to the git this demo, just comment.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will create a small project and check again. And i can't push my project, because it is a project of my company.